# Find length of a line in similar triangles

Tags: trigonometry

I have a triangle same as in this image:

[image: Triangle]

I want to find the length of $DE$ while $AC$, $AB$, $CB$, $CD$ are known.

Up to now I have tried to calculate it as follows:

$$L = \frac{AC\ (AB - CD)}{AB}$$

I am not sure whether this is right or not.

Comment: `BD/BC=DE/CA` with `BD=BC-CD` so `(CA*(BC-CD))/BC`. That's 14yo geometry..

Comment: Thnx a lot @Öskå

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{AC}{AB}&=\frac{DE}{BE}\\
(CB-CD)^2+DE^2&=BE^2\\
\end{align}
$$
Solve this system for $BE$ and $DE$